# Erro ao consumir API método post no react native ( ERROR [TypeError: Network request failed] )

Tags: javascript, react, api, axios, fetch

Estou tendo um problema com consumo de API no react native. Irei mostrar uma parte do código:

**Essa é a parte da API**

```
function cadastrarUsuarioCuidador(nome,email,password) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/autenticacao/registrar', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        nome: nome,
        email: email,
        senha: password,
      }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error)); 
  }
```

**Esse um dos input**

```
<TextInput
          style={styleCarevigerRegister.input}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          value={nome}
          placeholder="Nome completo"
        />
```

**Esse é o botão onpress**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styleCarevigerRegister.btnEnter} onPress={() =>        {          
          function register() {
            cadastrarUsuarioCuidador(nome,email,password)
          }
          function navegacao(){
            navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')
          }
          register()
          navegacao()
        }}>
```

Já tentei utilizar o Axios e recebo o mesmo erro de network, agora tentei o Fetch e deu o mesmo erro. Já tentei trocar o localhost para meu IP e também para o IP do android studio más mesmo assim sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

A partir da API 28 o Android não suporta http por defeito. Tens de adicionar isto à configuração:

```
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 .......>
 .......
</application>
```